# Android Manifest defines screen sizes but I cant see my app on the market.

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I submitted my app 3 days ago but I still cant see it on the market. Here is what I have defined in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true" 
                      android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be with `uses-feature` tag. Maybe your device doesn't have that features for your app(It can be gps, wifi, bluetooth). I'll suggest using `required=false` on those tags.

Comment: should also mention this is one of the features I am using: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<supports-screens 
                  android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"  
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"                  
                  android:anyDensity="true"
     />
```

and also checked the various uses permission tag, is it supported on your device? If not then it will not show on your device.

Comment: this is also good advice.... I added anyDensity. I dont want to support xLarge just yet because the layout looks whack.

Comment: Ok , I just give you all kinds of data :)